# Android RandomAccessFile usage from resource

Tags: java, android

How can I access an Android resource using `RandomAccessFile` in Java?

Here is how I would like this to work (but it doesn't):

```
String fileIn = resources.getResourceName(resourceID);
Log.e("fileIn", fileIn);
//BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileIn));

RandomAccessFile buffer = null;
try {
  buffer = new RandomAccessFile(fileIn, "r");
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  Log.e("err", ""+e);
}
```

Log output:

```
fileIn(6062): ls3d.gold.paper:raw/wwe_obj
```

The following exception appears in my console:

```
11-26 15:06:35.027: ERROR/err(6062): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /ls3d.gold.paper:raw/wwe_obj (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: I'm curious, how did you end up solving this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm using this code:

```
public static String readContentFromResourceFile(Context context, int resourceId)
throws IOException {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    final String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");

    InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String readLine = null;

    try {
        while ((readLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(readLine);
            sb.append(NEW_LINE);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        br.close();
        is.close();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: sorry, but i need randomaccessfile

Answer (score 2):

Like you, my situation is *much easier* if I can use an instance of `RandomAccessFile`. The solution I finally arrived at is to simply copy the resource into a file in cache, then open that file with `RandomAccessFile`:

```
/**
 * Copies raw resource to a cache file.
 * @return File reference to cache file.
 * @throws IOException
 */
private File createCacheFile(Context context, int resourceId, String filename)
    throws IOException {
  File cacheFile = new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);

  if (cacheFile.createNewFile() == false) {
    cacheFile.delete();
    cacheFile.createNewFile();
  }

  // from: InputStream to: FileOutputStream.
  InputStream inputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(resourceId);
  FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(cacheFile);
  int count;
  byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 512];
  while ((count = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);
  }

  fileOutputStream.close();
  inputStream.close();

  return cacheFile;
}
```

You would use this method thusly:

```
File cacheFile = createCacheFile(context, resourceId, "delete-me-please");
RandomAccessFile randomAccessFile = new RandomAccessFile(cacheFile, "r");

// Insert useful things that people want.

randomAccessFile.close();
cacheFile.delete();
```

Comment: would it be a good idea to make it autoclosable so it could be used with try-with-resources and get deleted automatically?

Comment: try with resources is always a great idea; the project I am working on does not support java 8 necessarily for instance; that happens a lot in android.

Answer (score 0):

Its a FileNotFound exception. That means that you do not specify well the file that you want to open at `String fileIn     = resources.getResourceName(resourceID);`

The problem is that Android can return to you only the `InputStream` of the raw file or a `FileDescriptor` but both are not enough for the `RandomAccessFile` constructor.

There is an open source library called [Unified I/O](http://reader.imagero.com/uio/) that you can use to achieve that you want, but I think that it will just make your project 'heavier'. Perhaps you should thought if you can avoid the RandomAccessFile somehow.

Comment: resourceID is R.raw.obj that is exists

Comment: ok, it exists but you have to specify the path of the raw folder, in order to be able to read it.

Comment: Hmmm, I think that now I realized your exact problem. See my edited answer. I found a library that can do what you want, but I am not sure if it is worth the try...